# Pandas, make the bars of a bar graph have equal widths

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, matplotlib, plotting

What do I need to change so that `ax1` uses the same width for bars as `ax2`?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

pd.Series([1]).plot(kind='bar', width=0.5, ax=ax1)
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).plot(kind='bar', width=0.5, ax=ax2)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [**the documentation**](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), it seems there is no obvious way.

Looking at [**the source code of the `plt.bar` method**](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6aec225620563af2a86fd064add2fa9eeb9e2045/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2166) (held on Axes objects), and searching for uses of the `width` parameter, it starts getting quite complicated and I don't think it is meant to be used for this purpose explicitly! Lots of internal methods, starting with a `_`, like [self._convert_dx](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6aec225620563af2a86fd064add2fa9eeb9e2045/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2337) is a clue.

I would just offer a nasty hack for your toy example, hoping it is applicable to your actual data:

```
In [1] : import pandas as pd 
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
    ...:  
    ...: fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2) 
    ...:  
    ...: pd.Series([0, 1, 0]).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1) 
    ...: pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2)
```

Gives

[image: Aligned bars]

So the hack is to make the length of your datasets the same, adding zeros where needed.

Answer (score 1):

n1k31t4 provided an interesting view that made me realize that the width depends on the limits of x axis. Learning that I made the following adjustments:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

width = .5

s1 = pd.Series(rd.randint(10, size=rd.randint(1, 10)))
s2 = pd.Series(rd.randint(10, size=rd.randint(1, 10)))

s1.plot(kind='bar', width=width, ax=ax1)
s2.plot(kind='bar', width=width, ax=ax2)

ax1.set_xlim([-width, (2 + len(s2)) * width])
ax2.set_xlim([-width, (2 + len(s2)) * width])
ax1.set_xlim([-.5, max(len(s1), len(s2)) - 1 + width])
ax2.set_xlim([-.5, max(len(s1), len(s2)) - 1 + width])

plt.show()
```

[image]

This seems to be universal enough while not requiring to touch the members of series.